# Click div to show/hide another

Tags: javascript

I want to have a div , and if you click that it shows another beneath it.
Both divs need to have text in it. I saw this on site but I don't know how to do this...

Comment: Do you mean an accordian? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: yes that is exactly what i mean

Comment: Please find the answer below and mark it as accepted if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like you need an accordian.

I would suggest using the [jQuery UI Accordian](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

Working Demo of jQuery UI Accordian:

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
      ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
      amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
      odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
      purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
      velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
      suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
      Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
      ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
      lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
      et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
      faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
      mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
      Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
      Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
      inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Omg..did you do any research on it?

First of all the second div needs to be hidden, second, add a click function to the first div to make it fadeIn...damn...

```
$('#div2').hide();
```

OR using CSS

```
#div2{display:none;}
```

and now the click function

```
$('#div1').click(function(){
   $('#div2').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two" style="display:none;">Two</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('one').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'block';
});
</script>
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding an EventListener to the first div:

HTML:

```
<div id="one">firstdiv</div><div id="two" style="display:none">seconddiv</div>
```

JS:

```
var a = document.getElementById('one'); // get the element
var b = document.getElementById('two'); //  ---- " ----

a.addEventListener('click',showhide);   // listen on the event 'click' and call a function

function showhide () {
    if (b.style.display == 'none') {    // check if the element is visible
    b.style.display = 'block';          // if it's not visible, show it
    }
    else {
        b.style.display = 'none';       // else it's visible, hide it
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sg6yujoa/1)

Answer (score -1):

jQuery is what you are looking for.